# Bold text on webpages when "Bold Text" iOS settings enabled

Tags: html, ios, accessibility

I would like to increase the font weight of the text content in the webpage when the iOS "Bold Text" settings is enabled. But, I'm not able to find any documentation about it online.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the `system-ui` font. I've made a quick [Codepen](https://codepen.io/beingfrankly/pen/qBYGLKj) to check it out. If you enable the "Bold Text" option on iOS it will change the font weight for the `p` that uses the `system-ui` as its `font-family`. And you can see that the `p` with the custom font, Poppins, isn't bold.